# Outputing a text file for user to see

Tags: html, coldfusion

I've been able to use  tags to show a pdf file to user this way:

```
<div>
   <object data="/Reports/PDF/#Trim(RptName)#_NewReport.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="860" height="700">
   </object>
</div>
```

Is it also possible to do this for any file other than a pdf file? I need to also show to my users their log file, UserName_Error.log. I tried the following and nothing showed up, the log is there. I googled for tips and could not find it.

```
<div>
   <object data="/Reports/UserError/#Trim(UserName)#_Error.log" type="text/html" width="860" height="700">
   </object>
</div>
```

If this is not possible at all?

Comment: this could be a good starting point -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450921/show-a-txt-file-on-a-webpage-which-updates-every-second

Comment: You can read text files using either `<cffile>` or `<cfhttp>`.  Details are in the manual which is available on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Use `iframe`.

> The **HTML `<iframe>` element** represents a nested browsing context, effectively embedding another HTML page into the current page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: difference between iframe, embed and object elements
: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660559/difference-between-iframe-embed-and-object-elements/